# VSCode SFDX: Retrieve Source from Org failing

Tags: salesforcedx

I have Lightning Web Components called myList, and when I try to do `SFDX: Retrieve Source from Org`, to get my classes from Apex class, I get the following error:

> 20:32:09.428 Starting SFDX: Retrieve Source from Org === Retrieve Warnings FULL NAME TYPE
> MESSAGE
> ───────── ────────────────────────
> ──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
> myList
> LightningComponentBundle Entity of type 'LightningComponentBundle' named 'myList' cannot be found
> 20:32:10.344 ended SFDX: Retrieve Source from Org

And something else. If I'm trying to do `SFDX: Retrieve Source from Org` and I have no Lightning Web Components in the lwc folder, I get the following error:

> 19: 21: 30.12 Starting SFDX: Retrieve Source from Org
> No components in the package to retrieve

I do not understand the connection between Retrieve Source from Org and Lightning Web Components in the project. I would love an explanation!

Comment: What is exact command you are running and  if you have what is package.xml can you share that?

Comment: Note for others: Based on the commands included in the question, these are being executed from the command palette of VS Code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I created a new project with the command: `SFDX: Create Project with Manifest`.

Then right-click on the package.xml file in the manifest folder, and select `SFDX: Retrieve Source in Manefist from Org`.

It worked.

Comment: This helped me too, thanks!